# API response data best practise - nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

For a certain internal endpoint I am working on for a `Nodejs` API, I have been asked  to dynamically change the value of a property `status` based on the value of a property `visibility` of the same object just before sending down the response.

So for example lets say I have an object that represents a user's profile. The user can have `visibility` Live or Hidden but `status` can be **IDLE**, **CREATING**, **UPDATING**.

What's been asked of me is that when I send down the object response containing those two properties I override the `status` value with another based on the current value of `visibility` - so if `visibility` is LIVE then I should set `status` to **ACTIVE**, if `visibility` is **HIDDEN** then `status` should be **INACTIVE** (two status values that do not exist internally in the database or in the list of enums for this object) and then also if `status` is not **IDLE** I should change it's value to **BUSY**

So not only am I changing it's value based on the value of `visibility` but I'm also changing it's value based on it's own value not being a value!

I am just wondering if this is good practice for an API in any way (apart from some weird extra layer of complexity, and so much inconsistency as the client will later ask for the same object based on status too, which means a reverse mapping)?

Comment: There's no reason the server and databases internal representation of `status` needs to have anything to do with the client's understanding of `status` (and there may be good reason to mask it if it is sensitive). Unless I'm mistaken, the whole purpose of such an API is to translate between the back-end and the front-end, right?

Comment: The status is not sensitive information and could easily be sent to the client as the client is an internal tool.

Comment: then it looks like there may be a need to have a talk with the users of that tool to understand why they want this translation.  There must be a reason they want the change otherwise it wouldn't have been asked for. They may have a point if not maybe it's an XY problem and you should really be working on Y

Answer (score 0):

`status` doesn't mean the same thing for different users, having the same name may be confusing but not a problem if well documented.

If the mapping become too complex, you can always persist the two values, but then you will have to keep them in sync.